# jquery getting html elements by type and class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get a list of link titles from a wikipedia page. I downloaded the HTML and now I'm trying to run some javascript/jquery code to get this going. Here's what I have so far...

```
var elements = $("ul > li");
alert(elements.length);
alert(elements.get(0).val());
```

The first alert gives me "505", which looks about right (there's quite a few of these elements).

My questions are how do I filter elements `$("ul > li")` by class name as well? Say the particular elements I want have class "class1".

The second alert doesn't give me anything, though `elements.get(0)` tells me `object HTMLLIelement` which is good I guess. So I'm not able to access a particular property that I want (say, 'title').

Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: [Here](http://api.jquery.com/) you can find up-to-date jQuery documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My questions are how do I filter elements $("ul > li") by class name as well? Say the particular elements I want have class "class1".

It's all [CSS selector syntax](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

```
$("ul > li.class1")
```

---

> The second alert doesn't give me anything, though elements.get(0) tells me "object HTMLLIelement" which is good I guess.

This is because [`.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get) returns a plain DOM element, not a jQueryified one. Use [`.eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq) instead:

```
elements.eq(0).val();
// to get the title:
elements.eq(0).prop('title');
// or if you're using jQuery <1.6,
elements.eq(0).attr('title');
```

---

> if the (ul > li) element has 3 "a" (link) elements that I want, how do I get the first one?

Use [`:first`](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) or [`.first()`](http://api.jquery.com/first).

Comment: Oh ok thanks. One more question: if the (ul > li) element has 3 "a" (link) elements that I want, how do I get the first one?

Answer (score 1):

$("ul > li.className") should be all you need.

Answer (score 1):

how do I filter elements $("ul > li") by class name as well?

```
$("ul > li.class1")
```

To get title attribute:

```
elements.eq(0).attr('title');
```

Comment: `elements.get(0).attr('title');` Nope. See my answer.

Comment: yeah realized that after I posted, I copied the OP's code rather than typing it out.